# rtmp Nginx use control endpoint for record?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I have nginx compiled with the [rtmp module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). I start `nginx` and run the following to start streaming my webcam which works:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

I then try to use the [control module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Control-module) to start recording:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/control/record/start?app=application&name=test&rec=rec1"
```

But the recording event doesn't seem to trigger.

Here is a simplified version of my `nginx.conf` file:

```
rtmp {                                                                    
  server {                                                                
  # ... more code here                                                    
    recorder rec1 {                                                       
      record all manual;                                                  
      record_suffix all.flv;                                              
      record_path /tmp/rec;                                               
      record_unique on;                                                   
    }                                                                     
  }                                                                       
}                                                                         

http {                                                                    
  server {                                                                
    listen 8080;                                                          
    server_name localhost;                                                
    location /control {                                                   
      rtmp_control all;                                                   
    }                                                                     
  }                                                                       
  # ... more code here                                                    
}
```

*Note: checked both port 8080 and 1935 are open with `nmap`.*

***Note/Update:***

I noticed that if I change `app=` to `live` I get an actual error message:

```
<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

*As opposed to the command with the actual app name which returns nothing. This tells me it is working to some extent but I still don't end up with a recoding.*

*I'm also trying to switch `name=test` to `name=live` neither causes an error response.*

[*Complete nginx.conf file.*](https://gist.github.com/kirkins/fb811f8caf34d3cdf1d9874050fb1a62)

***Update #2:***

I'm watching `/var/log/nginx/error.log` while I use the `curl` command above. Everytime I use it the following is logged:

```
client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

Comment: Post the complete nginx config and just parts of it

Comment: @TarunLalwani https://gist.github.com/kirkins/fb811f8caf34d3cdf1d9874050fb1a62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eneded up fixing this. The problem was two fold.

1. application wasn't my application name, it was `live`.
2. the `rec1` block wasn't inside the live application block, it was an unrelated block of code for hls.